Hibernate 6 casts query parameters
Hi there got the following repository:
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo> {

  @Query(
  """
      SELECT o FROM Foo o 
      JOIN Fee e on o.feeId = e.id 
      JOIN Fii i on e.fiiId = i.id 
      WHERE i.id = :fiiId 
      AND o.id IN (
        SELECT u.id 
        FROM Fuu u  
        JOIN Foo o2 on u.fooId = o2.id 
        WHERE u.something LIKE CONCAT('%', :param1, '_', :param2, '%')
      )""")
  List<OptionRule> findByFiiIdAndFuuLikeSomeComputed(
     Long fiiId, String param1, char param2);
}

Notes:
u.something is a column defined like:
@Nullable
@Column(name = "SOMETHING", length = 25000)
private String something;

Prior to Hibernate 6:
select foo0_.ID                 as id1_18_,
       ...
from FOO foo0_
         inner join FEE fee1_ on (foo0_.FEE_ID = fee1_.ID)
         inner join FII fii2_ on (fee1_.FII_ID = fii2_.ID)
where fii2_.ID = ?
and (foo0_.ID in (select foo4_.ID
       from FUU fuu3_
                inner join FOO foo4_
                           on (fuu3_.FOO_ID = fuu4_.ID)
       where foo3.SOMETHING like '%' || ? || '_' || ? || '%'))

After I upgraded to Hibernate 6:

"Could not convert 'java.lang.Character' to 'java.lang.String' using 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType' to wrap" which I fixed by replacing: char with String.
The query now includes cast which is not supported by the DB2 z/OS.

Query:
select fo1_0.ID,
       ...
from FOO fo1_0
     join FEE fe1_0 on fo1_0.FEE_ID = fe1_0.ID
     join FII fi1_0 on fe1_0.FII_ID = fi1_0.ID
where fi1_0.ID = ?
and fo1_0.ID in (
    select 
      fo2_0.ID
    from FUU fu1_0
      join FOO fo2_0 on fu1_0.FOO_ID = fo2_0.ID
    where fu1_0.SOMETHING like cast('%' || cast(? as varchar(25000)) || '_' || cast(? as varchar(25000)) || '%' as varchar(32672)))

How can I remove the cast(? as ...) when using org.hibernate.dialect.DB2zDialect. My DB2 z/OS 12.xxx does not seem to support it.
I tried to find appropriate functions in SqlAstTranslator or SqlAstWalker and overwrote them, but it does not seem the generated query comes from here.
EDIT:
This is currently the Dialect I came up working so far, but the cast problem remains:
LegacyDb2Dialect.java
import org.hibernate.dialect.DB2zDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LegacyDB2LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitHandler;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlAstTranslator;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlAstTranslatorFactory;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.StandardSqlAstTranslatorFactory;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.Statement;
import org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcOperation;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformationExtractor;

public class LegacyDb2Dialect extends DB2zDialect {
  
  @Override
  public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
    return LegacyDB2LimitHandler.INSTANCE;
  }

  @Override
  public SqlAstTranslatorFactory getSqlAstTranslatorFactory() {
    return new StandardSqlAstTranslatorFactory() {
      @Override
      protected <T extends JdbcOperation> SqlAstTranslator<T> buildTranslator(
          SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Statement statement) {
        return new LegacyDb2SqlAstTranslator<>(sessionFactory, statement, getVersion());
      }
    };
  }
}

LegacyDb2SqlAstTranslator.java
import org.hibernate.dialect.DB2zSqlAstTranslator;
import org.hibernate.dialect.DatabaseVersion;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.Statement;
import org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcOperation;

public class LegacyDb2SqlAstTranslator<T extends JdbcOperation> extends DB2zSqlAstTranslator<T> {

  public LegacyDb2SqlAstTranslator(
      SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Statement statement, DatabaseVersion version) {
    super(sessionFactory, statement, version);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean supportsOffsetClause() {
    return false;
  }
}

EDIT:
I found out the casts are also done when using Specification/CriteriaBuilder and column types like bigint.

Try to remove the CONCAT from your query, by concatinating them in the code, instead of in the query.
E.g.
              WHERE u.something LIKE %:concatenatedParams%")
List<OptionRule> findByFiiIdAndFuuLikeSomeComputed(Long fiiId, String concatenatedParams);

  

